# how to exclude a database from cPanel backup

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I have a big database on my server, this database doen't need to be in my backup but other databases need to be in the backup.

How can I handle that?

I tried to exclude the folder in which the big database is located with "cpbackup-exclude.conf" but it doesn't work. I guess the cPanel backup use sql request to save database.

Comment: I could use the "--ignore-table" option in the sql request used by the cPanel backup conf file, but where is this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to the server as root (instead of WHM/cpanel login) and create your database in command line. Since this database will not be part of any cpanel domain structure, cpanel will not include it automatic backups...